# Recovering files after accidental reset

Tags: data-recovery, images

My father has done a reset to factory by accident.
We are trying to restore photos, videos and other if possible.

It seems that the recovery programs for android are not as good as the pc ones so I thought:
Is it possible to make a byte-by-byte copy/image of the smartphone and afterwards use pc programs to recover the files?

If you have any recommendation of such program to create the copy/image please share.

Thanks!

Comment: What Android version is running on that device? Check Android Settings if the device is encrypted. If it is then recovery programs should not be able to recover anything because a factory reset resets the encryption key and without that key all saved data turn to cryptographic glibberish.