# How to create an exact image of all the internal memory including the "free space"?

Tags: data-recovery, images

My father has done a reset by accident on his smartphone.

He has very important data he needs that was deleted.

Is there a software/app/way that will copy the internal memory (hard disk) exactly as it is byte-by-byte to my computer (**also copying the "empty" parts of the disk because this is where the deleted files I want to recover are located**)?

I want that as first step because I see there are a lot of different software that offer that but I would rather try more then 1 in order to extract as much data possible (they each have their pros and cons). Most of these programs also install an app or tweaks stuff on the phone and I would like to use each on the original copy.

Comment: Have you read my comment on your last question? You still don't name the Android version or the device model you use and if the device was encrypted because it it is then what you are trying to do is useless because encrypted data can not be recovered without the key.

Comment: raw dump: for Qualcomm chipset in EDL mode with edl.py, for Mediatek chipset in preloader mode with SP Flash Tool. but as [Robert](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236615/recovering-files-after-accidental-reset#comment313250_236615) already stated raw dump is useless because encryption keys are **UNRECOVERABLE** from factory reset

Comment: Pocophone f1
@Robert

Comment: Pocophone F1 is encrypted with full-disk-encryption. crypto footer is located at the end of userdata partition. userdata partition is formatted on factory reset. new crypto footer is created on boot. old crypto footer is overwritten and therefore unrecoverable. disk image is of no use for data recovery

Comment: Thanks @alecxs and @Robert!